# Uncorrelatedness + Joint Normality = Independence. Why? Intuition and mechanics

Tags: correlation, normal-distribution, independence, joint-distribution, intuition

Two variables that are uncorrelated are not necessarily independent, as is simply exemplified by the fact that $X$ and $X^2$ are uncorrelated but not independent. However, two variables that are uncorrelated AND jointly normally distributed are guaranteed to be independent. Can someone explain intuitively why this is true? What exactly does joint normality of two variables add to the knowledge of zero correlation between two variables, which leads us to conclude that these two variables MUST be independent?

Comment: It is not generally  the case that $X$ and $X^2$ are uncorrelated (unless you put particular conditions on the $X$ that would make them uncorrelated, but you mention none).

Comment: First, going back to the fact that correlation refers to linear relationships, please explain how X^2 is linearly related to X. Second, you seem to be stating that not only can X^2 and X be linearly related, but that they are linearly related more often than not, given the use of the word "generally". Please explain. Thank you.

Comment: @Glen_b is spot on: $X$ and $X^{2}$ are only uncorrelated if you specifically stipulate the range of $X$. For example Pearson's $r \approx 0.98$ for $X$ and $X^{2}$ when restricting the sample of $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ to values of $X$ in the range greater than 1. Check it out yourself (R): `X <- rnorm(n=10000); X2 <- X*X; cor(X[X>1],X2[X>1])`

Comment: @Alexis It's not just the range, but the how the probabilities distribute over those values within the range. If you change the distribution you change the correlation.

Comment: If $X$ and $X^3$ have expectations of $0$ (e.g nice distributions symmetric about $0$) then $X$ and $X^2$ are uncorrelated

Comment: @ColorStatistics correlation is the degree of linear relationship, yes. However, the projection of $x^2$ onto $x$ may involve a substantial linear component. If you want to see an example with high linear correlation between a variable and its square, let $X$ take the values 0 and 1 with equal probability (e.g. record the number of heads in the toss of a single fair coin). Then corr$(X,X^2)=1$ (!). If you're free to specify the distribution of $X$, you can make the correlation between $X$ and $X^2$ take any value between $-1$ and $1$. ... ctd

Comment: @Glen_b Yes. Did not mean my wording to be as limited as it was. Wanted to provide an example with normally distributed $X$.

Comment: ctd ... For a continuously distributed example with high correlation, consider $X$ to be uniformly distributed between $100$ and $101$; the correlation between $X$ and $X^2$ is about $0.999999175$ (and we can make it exceed any value that's strictly below 1). To see when the covariance is 0: $\text{Cov}(X,X^2)=0\implies E(X^3)=E(X)E(X^2)$. This is easy to achieve when the distribution is symmetric about $0$ (though not always the case even then) but rarely the case otherwise.

Comment: @Alexis just make the mean (say) 10 and sd (say) 1.

Comment: Thank you Glen_b. This reminded me of the following: X and Y are independent if a pretty remarkable condition holds, described either as p(x,y)=p(x)*p(y) for all x and y, or as the rows and columns of p(x,y) all being proportional. Whenever this remarkable condition does not hold, x and y are not independent and thus dependent. I guess it is quite similar with correlation. Zero correlation or no correlation is quite a remarkable condition, although slightly less so than independence. Whenever this remarkable condition does not hold, two variables will have some degree of correlation.

Comment: Perhaps my answer below is a bit more "intuitive" than the other one.

Comment: It may well be, Michael. I will try to digest it once more. The first time around I found the answer quite complex and didn't really get the intuition, as in a clear "Aha, I get it now" moment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The the joint probability density function (pdf) of bivariate normal distribution is: 
 $$f(x_1,x_2)=\frac 1{2\pi\sigma_1\sigma_2\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\exp[-\frac z{2(1-\rho^2)}],  $$

where

$$z=\frac{(x_1-\mu_1)^2}{\sigma_1^2}-\frac{2\rho(x_1-\mu_1)(x_2-\mu_2)}{\sigma_1\sigma_2}+\frac{(x_2-\mu_2)^2}{\sigma_2^2}.$$ 
When $\rho = 0$,
$$\begin{align}f(x_1,x_2) &=\frac 1{2\pi\sigma_1\sigma_2}\exp[-\frac 12\left\{\frac{(x_1-\mu_1)^2}{\sigma_1^2}+\frac{(x_2-\mu_2)^2}{\sigma_2^2}\right\} ]\\
& = \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_1}\exp[-\frac 12\left\{\frac{(x_1-\mu_1)^2}{\sigma_1^2}\right\}] \frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_2}\exp[-\frac 12\left\{\frac{(x_2-\mu_2)^2}{\sigma_2^2}\right\}]\\ &= f(x_1)f(x_2)\end{align}$$.

So they are independent.

Comment: I was two lines slower than you! (+1)

Comment: Thank you all. Elegant proof. It's clear now. It seems to me that given the flow of the proof, I should have asked what knowledge of zero correlation adds to knowledge of joint normality and not the other way around.

Comment: What about an intuitive explanation as to why it is true?

Comment: Maybe there is no intuitive simple explanation.

Comment: Could we get some intuition along the line of reasoning that a Gaussian process' higher (than 2) moments are all zero, and adding the zero correlation condition (moment 2), pins down all moments greater than one to zero?

Comment: what would be the graph of this be looking like?

Comment: @ColorStatistics I do not think your method is intuitive. Are you sure that a Gaussian process' higher (than 2) moments are all zero? I know for normal distribution the fourth central moment is not zero.

Comment: @PaariVendhan Think it in 3-D graph. X-Y plane for two random variables, Z axis is the joint density. Then the graph will look like a sand dune. The highest point is at the mean point of X and Y. cutting from any value of the z, you get a circle if independent. I am not good on R, otherwise, I can draw it.

Comment: but looks like your description fits any bivariate normal distribution graph? even if independent, it will be so? i visualize something like [this](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2xHeg6n89tU/maxresdefault.jpg)

Comment: That graph is what I described. Thank you. Cut the dune parallel to X-Y plane, you will get a circle if independent,  and you will get a oval if dependent.

Comment: @a_statistician From what I understand, this graph is helpful at showcasing dependence vs. independence but doesn't add anything to our mission here of understanding what zero correlation adds to joint normality to obtain independence

Comment: @ColorStatistics You are talking about that dune? You are right about it. For intuition, as I said before Maybe there is no intuitive simple explanation.

Comment: Indeed, I was. Thank you for clarifying it. We'll keep thinking about it.

Answer (score 2):

Joint normality of two random variables $X,Y$ can be characterized in either of two simple ways:

- For every pair $a,b$ of (non-random) real numbers, $aX+bY$ has a univariate normal distribution.
- There are random variables $Z_1,Z_2\sim\operatorname{\text{i.i.d.}} \operatorname N(0,1)$ and real numbers $a,b,c,d$ such that $$\begin{align} X & = aZ_1+bZ_2 \\ \text{and } Y & = cZ_1 + dZ_2. \end{align}$$

That the first of these follows from the second is easy to show. That the second follows from the first takes more work, and maybe I'll post on it soon . . .

If the second one it true, then $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y) = ac + bd.$

If this covariance is $0,$ then the vectors $(a,b),$ $(c,d)$ are orthogonal to each other. Then $X$ is a scalar multiple of the orthogonal projection of $(Z_1,Z_2)$ onto $(a,b)$ and $Y$ onto $(c,d).$

Now conjoin the fact of orthogonality with the circular symmetry of the joint density of $(Z_1,Z_2),$ to see that the distribution of $(X,Y)$ should be the same as the distribution of two random variables, one of which is a scalar multiple of the orthogonal projection of $(Z_1,Z_2)$ onto the $x$-axis, i.e. it is a scalar multiple of $Z_1,$ and the other is similarly a scalar multiple of $Z_2.$